# Auto Shutdown Spring Boot after Inactivity Timeout

Tags: spring-boot

I'm looking for a way to to have Spring Boot shut itself down after X minutes of receiving no requests.

I am aware of manual ways. I need it to be self-policing.

Suggestions?

Comment: maybe this link will help you [graceful shutdown](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-graceful-shutdown)

Comment: This looks  like the way to configure a graceful shutdown that has been manually initiated. I'm looking for a way to detect a period of no requests, say for 20 minutes, and automatically "gracefully" shut down.

Comment: you can use filter or interceptor to handle every request. in every request you update the last-activity in database. but you have to make a cron job to get last-activity time from db. when last-activity-time let's say > 20 minutes. then trigger job to gracefully shutdown the spring boot. To use spring interceptor, you can view this link [interceptor](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_interceptor.htm)